# How can I deploy an Asp.Net MVC Core application, using .Net Framework (not core) in my local IIS?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2017 the most obvious way to me is to publish to IIS using file system. When I host the folder that comes outof this publishing in IIS I use an App Pool with .Net 4.5.1 (I also use .Net 4.5.1 for my app). When I access the web page with the browser, static content works, but dynamic content returns HTTP 501 without further information.

In the events viewer I see no entries.

How can I diagnose this? Should I try another way to get the app running in the local IIS and later on an inhouse server using IIS?

Comment: As described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis "Set the .NET CLR version to No Managed Code." your IIS application pool shoudln't be running .Net and should be set to No Managed Code.

Comment: "No Managed Code", would never have thought about that. will try, thx

Comment: Yeah, it's a little bit strange at first. In that scenario, IIS is just acting as a reverse proxy, forwarding your request to the self hosting ASP.NET Core module that is also an autonomous application that will be using a .Net runtime.

Comment: woiking, thx. do you know if this proxy scenario performs well? at the moment i use it for dev only, but would be interested if iis-kestrel is recommended or should better be avoided.

Comment: Adding it as a response then, I wasn't sure it would be enough.

Comment: Regarding the performance, you can find information here and there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440649/iis-vs-kestrel-performance-comparison I wouldn't worry, because MS worked wrote a lot of thing from scratch to build ASP.NET Core, and they wouldn't have released something less performant.

Comment: @citykid: All kestrel-based ASP.NET Core applications are supposed to run behind a reverse proxy. Kestrel is not (yet) meant be run as internet facing service. When you use Weblistener (Windows only), then self-hosting w/o IIS as reverse proxy is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described here http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis "Set the .NET CLR version to No Managed Code." your IIS application pool shoudln't be running .Net and should be set to No Managed Code.